# Any idea how I pull those values?

Tags: php

```
foreach ($_GET as $field => $label) {
    $datarray[]=$_GET[$field];
    echo "$_GET[$field]";
    echo "<br>";
```

This is the output I am getting. I see the data is there in datarray but when I echo $_GET[$field] I only get "Array"

But print_r($datarray) prints all the data. Any idea how I pull those values?

OUTPUT:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Grade1
        [1] => ln
        [2] => North America
        [3] => yuiyyu
        [4] => iuy
        [5] => uiyui
        [6] => yui
        [7] => uiy
        [8] => 0:0:5
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: When I completed your test, here was the final URL:

> http://hofstrateach.org/Roberto/process.php?keys=Grade1&keys=Nathan&keys=North%20America&keys=5&keys=3&keys=no&keys=foo&keys=blat&keys=0%3A0%3A24>

This is probably a malformed URL. When you pass duplicate keys in a query, PHP makes them an array. The above URL should probably be something like:

http://hofstrateach.org/Roberto/process.php?grade=Grade1&schoolname=Nathan&region=North%20America&answer[]=5&answer[]=3&answer[]=no&answer[]=foo&answer[]=blat&time=0%3A0%3A24

This will create individual entries for most of the fields, and make $_GET['answer'] be an array of the answers provided by the user.

Bottom line: fix your Flash file.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
       foreach($value as $childKey => $childValue)
       {
          echo $childKey." ".$childValue;    // or assign them to an array
       }
    }
    else
       echo $key." ".$value;    // or assign them to an array

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `$_GET[$field]` is basically `$_GET[0]`, which is an array:

You'll have to loop through `$_GET[$field]` with a forloop to get the content to echo out.  By the way you can't echo array you'll have to use `print_r`

something like this:

```
foreach ($_GET as $field => $label) {
    $datarray[]=$_GET[$field];
    for($i=0; $i<$_GET[$field]; $i++){
        echo $_GET[$field][$i];
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```